# Como gerar um "token" na barra de link com javascript?

Tags: javascript

Queria saber se tem como gerar uns caracteres aleatórios no link numa página, sem ter que alterar o endereço da mesma.

Por exemplo, quando a pessoa clicar no link, será enviada para:

```
site.com/pages/pagina-de-destino.html
```

mas quero que o navegador exiba na barra de pesquisas:

```
site.com/pages/pagina-de-destino.html#access_token=(por volta de 160 caracteres aleatórios)
```

Como fazer isso em JavaScript/HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro do que foi perguntado, acho que isso resolve:

```js
var result = '';
for (var i = 80; i > 0; --i) result += (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)).toString(16);

document.getElementById( 'link' ).href += '#access_token=' + result;
```

```html
Ponha o mouse sobre o link e olhe a barra de status:<br>
<a id="link" href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107323/70">Link</a>
```

Só lembre-se que qualquer coisa em JS pode ser manipulada do lado do cliente.

Comment: Meu amigo, como e onde aplico esse js na página?
Desculpa, mas sou novato com JavaScript.

Não sei se afeta, mas, no projeto, o link está dentro da div "item", que está dentro da div "main"

Comment: Basta por o mesmo nome no ID do link e do getElementById, não importa onde esteja. O JS pode ser posto onde vc quiser da página também, ou carregado externamente, desde que seja executado.